# Pass multiple refs to child component with extra information

Tags: reactjs, react-props

Here is Articles component:

```
const Articles = ({articles}) => {

// articlesRefs - Map articles names to articles refs
// articleToLiRefs - Map articles refs to li refs
const [articlesRefs, articleToLiRefs] = useArticleLiRefs(articles);

// Code (...)

return (
<div>
    <nav><ul>
            { articles.map((article) => {
                
                const articleName = article.get('name');
                const articleRef = articlesRefs.get(articleName);
                const liRef = articleToLiRefs.get(articleRef);

                return (
                    <li
                        ref={liRef}
                        key={articleName}
                        onClick={()=> articleRef.current.scrollIntoView()}>
                        {articleName}
                    </li>
                );
            })}
        </ul></nav>
        {/* Code (...) */}
</div>
)}
```

I want to meke ArticlesNav component containing all nav information.
My **first approach:**
Just pass Maps with refs by props

```
const Articles = ({articles}) => {
...
return (
...
<ArticlesNav articles={articles} articlesRefs={articlesRefs} articleToLiRefs={articleToLiRefs}  />
```

And just copy and paste everything between nav tags to ArticlesNav. And it worked.

But you should not pass refs by props. There is forwardRef to pass refs. So here is my **second approach**:

```
const Articles = ({articles}) => {
...
const refsToForward = useRef([articlesRefs, articleToLiRefs]);
...
return (
...
<ArticlesNav articles={articles} ref={refsToForward} />
```

And inside ArticlesNav:

```
const ArticlesNav = forwardRef( ({articles}, ref ) => {

const [articlesRefs, articleToLiRefs] = ref.current;
```

Question is: What is the correct way to pass multiple refs in structure like Map ? Is any of these approaches correct ?